# Postman request works but my React request doesn't. Where is my mistake

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, frontend, fetch

I'm making a basic full stack to do app. I made backend with Java Spring. When I test the my backend with Postman it works well but when I send the same request with React fetch it doesn't work! I guess my fetch is wrong but I can't understand.

[image]

```
function register(){
fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/register',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                'userName' : 'Pala',
                'password' : 'sibop',
            }
        )
    }
).then(
    res => {
        console.log("Result: " + res)
    }
).catch(
    err => {
        console.log("Erorororor: " + err)
    }
)}
function Home() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>To Do!</h1>
        <form>
        <div id="signupArea">
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <input id="userName"/>
            <h2>Password</h2>
            <input id="password" type="password"/>
            <button onClick={register}>SIGN UP</button>
            <button>LOGIN</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
)}export default Home
```

[image]

What is my problem?

Comment: your request was blocked by CORS, you have to config CORS policy, each backend handle this in a different way

Comment: The error is not in your code. You are facing a cross origin resource sharing issue. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: By the way, the fetch api is not from react, but JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` to package.json and changed the fetch url to `"/auth/register"` and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure proxy, you got CORS error.

if you are using create-react-app.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/